# Social buttons performance

Tags: php, html, performance, share-button

I have performance issues with my gallery once i added social buttons.

The gallery currently has around 30 thumbnails, for each there are four social buttons for various service (fb,g+,twitter,pinterest).

But my pageload jumped up to thirty or more seconds rendering the page useless.

My question is : Can i somehow adjust the plugins so they load faster ?
Should i maybe change my approach and display these "on demand" ?
Or maybe should i divide the gallery into more pages so there is not so many of these at the same time ?

Comment: Any CMS are you use (wordpress, Joomla, Drupal) or static PHP ?

Comment: Are the images for these social buttons from the social networks CDN or are the images on your server?

Comment: I'm not using any CMS in this project

Comment: Images are provided by the social services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the images are hosted on the social networks servers you are making a request to their server each time to get the image. 4 images per thumbnail would be 120 requests which can add alot to the response time of your page.

I would suggest you host the images on your own server (maybe as a spritesheet) to reduce the amount of requests.

Comment: I did thought of this , but i thought once the image is downloaded for the first button, it is afterwards loaded from browsers cache. Is this not true ?

Comment: Although the images are from cache it still has to request the image from another server which happens each time for a button. Using your own server means only one request.

Comment: That is inconvenient. Accepting your answer.